# Convergence of a series if the coefficients are periodic.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $c_n$ is a periodic sequence -- although, for simplicity, I think we can just imagine that $c_{n+2}=c_n$ for all $n\ge 0$, since I doubt the period should matter.

Can we say anything about the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\ge 0}c_nx^{2n}$?  I would first think of the root test and examine

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_nx^{2n}|} = \lim_{n\to\infty}|c_n|^{1/n}|x|^2 $$

and with a little argument I think we can justify $\lim_{n\to\infty}|c_n|^{1/n} = 1$ so long as $c_n\ne 0$ for any $n\ge 0$.  This suggests that the interval of convergence is given by $|x|<1$.

On the other hand by the ratio test we need

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left| \frac{c_{n+1}x^{2n+2}}{c_nx^{2n}} \right| = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right||x|^2<1$$

But here it seems like we don't get the same result.

It seems like the ratio test is just inconclusive in this case, and that could make sense -- there is no reason why the ratio and root tests have to say the same things in all cases.  But it does make me wonder if I've reasoned through all of this correctly.

So is it correct that the root test implies convergence for any nonzero sequence $c_n$ in the interval $|x|<1$ as above, whereas the root test is inconclusive?

Comment: I agree the root test implies radius of convergence $1$ while the ratio test is inconclusive. It seems strange to see $x$ appear in these tests, however. Also why $x^{2n}$ rather than $x^n$?

Comment: It seems ratio test gives $c_0/c_1$ as radius since the coefficients are periodic. But is it possible to get 2 different radii ?

Comment: The ratio test is inconclusive (which can happen); the root test gives the correct answer.

Comment: @DavidK I threw that in there just in case somehow there being a period of 2 and somehow "skipping every other term" somehow mattered.  I figured it wouldn't but I also figured it wouldn't hurt to throw it in and see if anyone had an interesting observation.

Comment: @Cretin2 No, one of the important theorems about radii of convergence is that any given series has a uniquely determined radius of convergence.  So what must be going on here is that the ratio test is simply useless in this case.

Comment: Regarding your comment on the failure of the ratio test, the root test is strictly stronger than the ratio test. If the ratio test succeeds (gives something $\neq 1$), then so does the root test. This is proved in Rudin's Principles.

Comment: Yes, my fault, it gives $|x|\leq min(|c_0/c_1|,|c_1/c_0|)\leq 1$ for ratio test (it seems ?)

Comment: @Cretin2: In fact the radius of convergence is $\ge \min (c_0/c_1, c_1/c_0)$  since  $\min\le 1$ and radius $=1$  ( assume the sequence is not $\equiv 0$).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

Comment: @orangeskid. Yes my comment also lacks a square root for period 2 as given in the op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way of seeing that the radius of convergence is indeed $1$ (assuming that the sequence $\{c_n\}$ is not identically zero).

Suppose that $p$ is a positive integer such that $c_{n+p}=c_n$ for all $n\ge0$. Then
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n = \sum_{a=0}^{p-1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{kp+a}x^{kp+a} = \sum_{a=0}^{p-1} c_a x^a \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{kp},
$$
and the inner sum converges when $|x|<1$ (to $\dfrac1{1-x^p}$) and diverges otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

The radius of convergence equals

$$R= \lim \inf_{n\to \infty}\  \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}$$

If $(c_n)_n$ is periodic,  this is $\infty$ or $1$, according to $c_n \equiv 0$ or not.

Note that in general we have

$$\lim \inf\left| \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right| \le \lim \inf \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}} \le \lim \sup \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}\le \lim \sup \left| \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right|$$

so we should only use $\left| \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right|$ when this sequence is  convergent.

$\bf{Added:}$ Let's see how this works with the sequence

$$c_n = \begin{cases} 2^n \text{ if } n \text{ even} \\
                     3^n \text{ if } n \text { odd} 
         \end{cases} $$

We have

$$\lim \inf_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}} = \frac{1}{3}\\
\lim \sup_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\lim \inf_{n\to \infty} \frac{|c_n|}{|c_{n+1}|} = 0\\
  \lim \sup_{n\to \infty} \frac{|c_n|}{|c_{n+1}|} = \infty$$

So the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n\ge 0} c_n x^n$ is $\frac{1}{3}$. Moreover, the ratio test does not work.

We can also find the radius of convergence by computing the function and see the largest disk centered at $0$ on which the function is defined. So we compute
$$\sum c_n x^n = \sum_{n\ge 0} 2^{2n} x^{2n} + \sum_{n\ge 0} 3^{2n+1} x^{2n+1} = \frac{1}{1- (2 x)^2} + \frac{3 x}{1- (3 x)^2}$$
Examining the denominators, we see that the largest disk has around $0$ on which the function is defined has radius $\frac{1}{3}$, which also equals the radius of convergence of the series ( a general fact,  due to Cauchy).